# How to make numbers Iterable in python?

Tags: python, list, integer

How can we iterate over a collection of integers in python or How can we make the collection of numbers into a list in python?

As I was trying to iterate over integers I got Error.

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

input is n = 7849 9594 9699

```
n = input()
n1, n2, n3 = list(map(int, n.split(' ')))

for i in n1:
print(i)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:/Python code/wipro - 2.py", line 5, in

for i in n1:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

So my question how can I make n1 iterable or how can I convert n1,n2,n3 into lists?

I want,

```
   n1 = 7849 (as list)

   n2 = 9594 (as list)

   n3 = 9699 (as list)
```

so that I can perform list functions on n1,n2,n3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the confusion is the idea of "as a list". My best guess is that what you want is

```
n1 = ['7', '8', '4', '9']
n2 = ['9', '5', '9', '4']
n3 = ['9', '6', '9', '9']
```

So you could probably just use

```py
n1, n2, n3 = list(map(list, n.split(' ')))
```

or something like that. There's room for optimization, but without knowing your use-case it's hard to say what would be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need three objects after splitting if you need a list.

Use this to get a list after splitting the input:

```
n = input()
n1 = list(map(int, n.split(' ')))

for i in n1:
    print(i)
```

Comment: n = 7849 9594 9699, so I want this input to split into 3 separate list, 7849 as a list, 9594 as a another list, and 9699 as another list. I want those splitted number into separate list and want to iterate over them

Comment: `n1` is a list. please verify the above code and describe if you need something?